# How to call a collection that is a number

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

in my mongoDB database I have collections named as numbers. For example

```
db.15.find()
```

If you don't already know this returns an error. How do I go about getting documents id a collection that is named a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [getCollection()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/) method.

For your example you get:

```
db.getCollection('15').find();
```

HTH -
Rob.